# Getting a message from sqlanywhere in c#

Tags: c#, sqlanywhere

In SQL Anywhere you can raise MESSAGES , eg:

```
MESSAGE 'Hello World' TO CONSOLE
```

the message is displayed in the client window of the server.

```
MESSAGE 'Hello World' TYPE INFO TO CLIENT FOR ALL
```

should send it to the clients.

Using a SAConnection it is possible to point to a void Method for InfoMessages

```
SAConnection con; ...
con.InfoMessage += new SAInfoMessageEventHandler(myMethod);
```

Even if I raise messages as above, they are only shown in the small server startup window (with TO CONSOLE), but the method is never called (with TO CLIENT).

So I have the following questions:

> 1. Is the InfoMessage really the thing wich listens to MESSAGE?
> 2. If not, what can I do to raise a InfoMessage?
> 3. Is there any way to get the MESSAGE in C#?